# How to use Google Guice with struts (aka. struts 1)?

Tags: struts, guice

This problem is not related to struts 2.

I failed to find a solution to use guice inject my struts action, and seems no one talks about it. Is this too dumb a question or it is just impossible?

Thanks.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve but may be [this](http://java-points.blogspot.com/2009/10/struts-1-and-guice.html) will help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I comes with this:

```
@Override
public void setServlet(ActionServlet servlet) {
        super.setServlet(servlet);
        ServletContext context = servlet.getServletContext();
        Injector injector = (Injector)  context.getAttribute(MyGuiceServletContextListener.KEY);
            ......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To use Google Guice with struts 1 refer: https://code.google.com/p/google-guice-aop-struts1-integration/

Try this.